# How can I use DataProvider and CGridView in Yii to display array in array data?

Tags: php, arrays, yii

now i have the code like this:

```
$testArray1 = array(array(
                    'user_id'=>'1',
                    'name'=>array(
                        'david',
                        'haword'),
                    ),
                    array(
                    'user_id'=>'2',
                    'name'=>'andrew',
                    ),
            );

            print_r($testArray1);
            $arrayDataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider ($testArray1,array(
                //'KeyField'=>'_id',
                'pagination'=>array(
                    'pageSize'=>10,
                ),
                'sort'=>array(
                ),
            ));
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'id' =>'BCImported-grid',
                'dataProvider' =>$arrayDataProvider,
                'columns' =>array('name'),
            ));
```

here is my result:

[image: the result picture]

so the form only display name = andrew,and name = david and haword is not display.
how can I use DataProvider and CGridView in Yii to display array in array data like name = david and haword where 'user_id'=>'1'?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to display array in CGridView except you custom that value.
create some static function in your model

```
public static function implodeName($data)
{
    if(isset($data['name'])) {
        if(is_array($data['name'])) {
            return implode(',', $data['name']);
        }
        else {
            return $data['name'];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

then in CGridView will be like this

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id' =>'BCImported-grid',
        'dataProvider' =>$arrayDataProvider,
        'columns' =>array(
            array(
              'header' => 'Names',
              'name' => 'name',
              'value' => 'YourModelName::implodeName($data)'
            ),
        ),
 ));
```

and the result should be : 
david, hawords

Comment: thank you.but I think it should be `if(isset($data[0]['name']))` right? and now my code is `'value' => '"'.implodeName($data[0]).'"',` but now it only always display 'name' of $data[0], I dont know how to dispaly 'name' of $data[0] and $data[1] .could you help me please?

Comment: you don't have to pass $data[0] to implodeName() function, just passed $data it self, the function already handle it and also in your CArrayDataProvider instance try to add id property before pagination

`'id' => 'user_id'`

Comment: see here [http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/378/an-important-tip-when-you-are-using-carraydataprovider/]